# Should we have a feature identification tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

We regularly see questions asking for people to identify a certain feature on an aircraft and they're normally tagged aircraft design.

Should we have a dedicated tag for these kinds of questions?

## Examples

[What is this on the starboard engine of the Dash 8?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37398/what-is-this-on-the-starboard-engine-of-the-dash-8)
[What is this ring-shaped device behind this DC-8's jet engine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37332/what-is-this-ring-shaped-device-behind-this-dc-8s-jet-engine)
[What exactly are those openings in the bellies of many jetliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16566/what-exactly-are-those-openings-in-the-bellies-of-many-jetliners)
[What is this protrusion on the door?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25398/what-is-this-protrusion-on-the-door)
[What is this nose cowl mounted display?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38065/what-is-this-nose-cowl-mounted-display)
[What is the function of the protruding outlet on the Trent XWB?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35000/what-is-the-function-of-the-protruding-outlet-on-the-trent-xwb)

Comment: agreed (comment now not short)

Comment: See my answer [here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3248/62) for some thoughts. If you think a tag is useful then you're always welcome to add it, but that's no guarantee that others will also use it.

Comment: @Pondlife any suggestions for a name for such a tag?

Comment: @ymb1 any suggestions for a name?

Comment: Something like "what-is-this" might be discoverable but not sure if it would be a "proper" tag.

Comment: @Notts90 - I suggest feature- or part-identification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree a tag would be useful. Although I doubt anyone *asking* the question will use the tag - it will likely have to be re-tagged by someone in the community.

I suggest "feature-identification" - "For questions about identifying a feature or design on an aircraft".

Comment: People asking the question are not too likely to reach for it on their own, true. However, if the tag entry box were to suggest it for all questions that started with "What is..."...